# Reading text file into array using Scanner: Null Pointer Exception

Tags: arrays, file, text, java.util.scanner

Im trying to read an archive file and pass it to an array but i keep getting Null Pointer Exception when i try to access to array[0]. When i asked java to print array[0] it shows null. This is the way i read the text file:

```
int lines= 0;
while(s1.hasNext()) {String line=s1.next(); lines ++; } // The number of lines


int i= 0;

char [][] array= new char [lines][]; 
if (f.exists()) {
while (s1.hasNext()) {
String line= s1.next(); 

int m = line.length();

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        array[i][j]=line.charAt(j);
    }

  i++;

} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array[0]` must be `null`, because you haven't allocated memory for that.

There are some more problems:

The second `while(s1.hasNext())` loop will never be executed, because the first one will read through the whole file, and when that ends, `s1.hasNext()` will return `false`. So the second loop will never run.

`array` is initiated with `lines` number of `char` arrays, but none of the arrays are initialized. So they all are `null`. When you try to access any of them, certainly you'll get a `NullPointerException`!